# How to get the generated scheme file .graphqls using SPQR?

Tags: java, graphql-java, graphql-spqr

I really like the way SPQR makes easy to integrate [graphql](/questions/tagged/graphql) with an existing system, the only thing I'd like to see is the `.graphqls` file so I can learn more on GraphQL Syntax.

Is there a way to generate the scheme file from an existing code with SPQR annotations integrated?

To provide some code let's use the same code from the [GitHub site](https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr)

Entity:

```
public class User {

    private String name;
    private Integer id;
    private Date registrationDate;

    @GraphQLQuery(name = "name", description = "A person's name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @GraphQLQuery
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @GraphQLQuery(name = "regDate", description = "Date of registration")
    public Date getRegistrationDate() {
        return registrationDate;
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
class UserService {

    @GraphQLQuery(name = "user")
    public User getById(@GraphQLArgument(name = "id") Integer id) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
type User {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    registrationDate: String
}

Query{
 user(Int):User 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not really SPQR specific. All the needed classes are provided by graphql-java itself:

```
new SchemaPrinter().print(schema);
```

To get a more detailed output (with scalars, introspection types etc), provide the options to the printer:

```
new SchemaPrinter(
                  // Tweak the options accordingly
                  SchemaPrinter.Options.defaultOptions()
                          .includeScalarTypes(true)
                          .includeExtendedScalarTypes(true)
                          .includeIntrospectionTypes(true)
                          .includeSchemaDefintion(true)
            ).print(schema);
```

Comment: I'm using spqr-spring-boot-starter library. Could you please help me how to get an instance for `schema` in your above code snippet?

Comment: @Anita You should be able to simply inject it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `graphql.spqr.gui.enabled=true` in the application properties enables the `gui(playground)`. The schema and documentation can be explored and downloaded from the GUI.