# Is there any way to create API documentation for graphql end points in a spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, documentation, graphiql

I have a springboot microservice project and I am using graphql. For REST api end points I am aware that we can document using swagger etc.. Graphiql also provides dynamic documentation but is there any other way to create API documentation for the customers who are not so aware of how graphql or Graphiql works.

Comment: I have the same question.   GraphQL-spqr automatically generates a graphql *schema*. I am still looking for a way to access/read/see this automatically generated schema. GraphiQL does not show it.

Answer (score 0):

aaah that might help: You can get (and print) the generated schema programatically:

[How to get the generated scheme file .graphqls using SPQR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086525/how-to-get-the-generated-scheme-file-graphqls-using-spqr)